# Problems with special scandinavian characters reading big txt file

Tags: r, encoding, special-characters, readr

I'm reading a 1 gb txt file containing Swedish letters å ä ö using (readr) and (Laf) packages

```
my.data<- read_fwf('my.file', fwf_widths (c(2,2,2,8,2,4,40,1,1,10,10,4,2,11,32,1,4)),
progress = interactive())
```

Getting values like    instead of ö ä å

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Scandinavian Characters sometimes require a special encoding, namely #ISO-8859-1 - Latin 1. Here are useful commands regarding encoding (which differs for each computing/OS)

```
#Check what is your present encoding:
getOption("encoding")
#Modifiy the encoding
options(encoding = "ISO-8859-1")

#Optional: Check your system locale (Time, Monetary System, etc)
Sys.getlocale()
#Set an encoding, but it is OS-dependent what is installed
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", locale ="swe")
```

From readr documentation: "Default encoding. This only affects how the file is read - readr always converts the output to UTF-8." With `read_fwf` it seems you can specifiy a locale/encoding:

```
read_fwf(file, col_positions, col_types = NULL, locale = default_locale(),
na = c("", "NA"), comment = "", skip = 0, n_max = Inf,
guess_max = min(n_max, 1000), progress = show_progress())
```

Replace `default_locale()` with `locale(encoding= "latin1")`. Your example is not reproductible, therefore it is difficult to test if it works, but it should look like:

```
my.data<- read_fwf('my.file', fwf_widths (c(2,2,2,8,2,4,40,1,1,10,10,4,2,11,32,1,4)), locale= locale(encoding= "latin1"),
progress = interactive())
```